# Flask doesn't see config value from config file

Tags: python, flask

I want to save a variable in a config file.  I declared `MY_KEY` in `config.cfg`.  I tried accessing it from `flask.config['MY_KEY']` but got `KeyError: 'MY_KEY'`.  How do I access this value?

```
MY_KEY = b'\xbf\xc0\x85)\x10nc\x64\x01)j\xdd\xcs\xcs\x94\e9d(\x5r[EX\xc8\xd5\xbfI{\xa2$\x05(\cd5\x17'
```

```
from flask import current_app
key = current_app.config['MY_KEY']
KeyError: 'MY_KEY'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have [loaded the configuration](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#configuration) when creating the app in order for it to be available in `app.config`.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile('path/to/config.cfg')
```

Then you can access the config as you expect.

```
key = current_app.config['MY_KEY']
```